# Reliable Change Index Question

Tags: reliability

I was wondering if someone could help me with a reliable change index question. I am looking to do pre/post analysis at the individual participant level. Is this method only appropriate for measures such as surveys where internal consistency (cronbach's alpha) can be calculated? Or is it possible to use another indicator of reliability? I am working with physiological and behavioural performance data, so internal consistency as measured by chronbach's alpha would not be appropriate.

Thanks!!